# Can I mark an email as read on the Apple Watch?

Tags: email, notifications, apple-watch, watchos

After I receive an email, I can preview it easily from the notification. If it's just an email I don't need to react, my workflow is to just leave it there as read. However, I can't seem to figure out how to mark an email as read on the Apple Watch, so now I have to dismiss the notification, take out my phone, force touch the email and mark as read.

The option on the bottom of the notification are ’Reply’, ‘Flag’, ‘Delete’, ‘Mark as unread’ and ‘Dismiss’. What is the difference between ‘Mark as unread’ and ‘Dismiss’, since both leave the message as unread. Shouldn't ‘Mark as unread’ be ‘Mark as read’ instead?

Comment: Is this the default iOS email client on your iPhone?  If so, have you tried 3rd-party apps instead?  If the option to 'mark as read' isn't displayed, there's no change (that I'm aware) to add that option.  Perhaps a different email client would provide that choice for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved by switching from the stock Mail app to [Spark](https://sparkmailapp.com). This client has the much needed "Mark as read" option.

Note that there are [some](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/48o408/spark_by_readdle_is_it_secure/) [concerns](https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/5grsan/do_not_use_the_spark_email_client_by_readdle/) [about](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/5grwsn/do_you_care_about_your_privacy_then_do_not_use/) [privacy](https://blog.readdle.com/how-we-handle-your-account-information-in-spark-1b42f4acef73) with this client, so consider the tradeoff between benefits and risks first.

Answer (score 1):

When you've previewed the email, that's marked it as read. Therefore the option is to undo this action and mark it unread. If you just want to leave it read after you've previewed it, close the notification and it'll be read.

Comment: I don't preview the email, I just skim the notification, like I would on my iPhone lock screen. This doesn't mark the email as read, I have to tap the message open and then press the crown to close.